# Get element from sequence in clojure

Tags: clojure, nested-lists, lazy-sequences

I understand that lists and vectors in Clojure can be used almost interchangeably in most situations.  Here is a simple case that surprised me

```
(nth [2 4] 0) ;=> 2
(nth '(2 4) 0) ;=> 2
(get [2 4] 0) ;=> 2
(get '(2 4) 0) ;=> nil -- wtf???
```

The documentation of `get` talks mapping a key, but it works with vectors or sets just fine.  The documentation of `nth` even mentions `get`, talking about their differences only in edge-cases.

The real-world situation where I faced this weird behavior was that I loaded a yaml file.  It resulted in a nested structure of maps and lists.  I wanted to access an element with `get-in`.

```
(def form (parse-yaml some-yaml-file))
(def best-friend (get-in form [:friends 0 :first-name]))
```

It doesn't work, because `get-in` uses `get` internally.  So I have a theoretical and a practical question:

- Is this behavior of `get` considered correct and expected?  If so, please, explain why.
- How can I access a nested element in such a structure of maps and lists?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The behaviour of `get` is correct and expected. `get` works on "keyed" data structures, in which values are mapped to keys. This includes vectors, which map indices to values<sup>1</sup>, and sets<sup>2</sup>.

Lists do not provide random access to elements; they're meant to be traversed linearly. Since the supported access patterns are so different, lists and vectors are *absolutely not* meant to be used interchangeably and the core Clojure collections library makes no effort to support such usage. (`nth` is an odd example of a function which does perform both low-performance constant-or-logarithmic-time lookups *and* linear traversals; a strange beast in Clojure land).

There are of course further differences to do with "modification" (in the persistent data structure sense: creating modified copies), such as the way in which `conj` works and the availability of `assoc` for vectors (as already mentioned in a footnote; replacing an element in a list involves rebuilding the entire prefix up to that point).

If you'd like to use vector-like access patterns with your data, you should put it in a vector. Lists can be converted to vectors (in linear time) with `vec`. If you're dealing with a serialization format where it's ambiguous whether lists or vectors should be returned for some data and your parser doesn't accept an option to tell it which it should use, you might have to do some post-processing yourself (`clojure.walk` might be useful, in particular the `prewalk` and `postwalk` functions; that's assuming only basic Clojure data types are involved).

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, more is true of vectors: they are associative, so you can use them with `assoc` (`(assoc [0 1 2] 0 :foo)` returns `[:foo 1 2]`; only indices up to `(count the-vector)` are supported, for `assoc`ing to indices which already exist in the vector and immediately past the end).

<sup>2</sup> For the purposes of this discussion, sets can be considered to map their members to themselves. This is actually true in Clojure in the sense that a set used as a function returns the member itself when applied to it -- and `nil` for non-members -- and also in the sense that that's what the implementation looks like under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

Code example supplement to Michał Marczyk's excellent answer:

```
(def form
  {:friends
  '({:id 1, :first-name "bob"}
    {:id 2, :first-name "sue"})
   :languages
  '({:id 1, :name "Clojure"})})

(-> form :friends (nth 0) :first-name)
;=> "bob"

(def form'
  (clojure.walk/prewalk #(if (list? %) (vec %) %) form))

(get-in form' [:friends 0 :first-name])
;=> "bob"
```